# Android Source change to pass intent invoker to Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, bundle

I am trying to modify the Android source so that a BroadcastReceiver can know who invoked the action.

android.app.activity:

```
@Override
public void startActivity(Intent intent) {      
    intent.putExtra("packageName", this.getPackageName());
    startActivity(intent, null);
}
```

I wrote a testing app that has the CALL_PHONE permission. As a debugging step, I also tried to see if I could just pass something in the Intent from the calling app:

Calling App (App #1):

```
Intent dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:8005551212"));
dialIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
dialIntent.putExtra("StubTest", "it worked!");
startActivity(dialIntent);
```

But in my BroadcastReceiver that intent does not have the intent value from the Activity source file change I made, nor the intent value I added from the invoking activity.

Separate App which has a Broadcast Receiver (App #2):

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    Set<String> k = bundle.keySet();
    if (k!=null && k.size() > 0) {
        Iterator<String> i = k.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            String key = i.next();
            try {
                System.out.println("KEY: " + key + "=" + bundle.getString(key));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logIt("skipping KEY: " + key);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(bundle.getString("packageName"));
    System.out.println(bundle.getString("StubTest"));
```

However, "packageName" and "StubTest" are both null all the time.

Comment: have you tried using intent.getStringExtra("StubTest") instead? and I do not know how do you get packageName when you did not actually set it anywhere else.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. "packageName" is set in startActivity. I modified the Android source for that method. (You can see I pasted my changes in my original post above.)